# Detecting stack exhaustion vs other sources of SIGSEGV

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, posix

In POSIX environments, when a process exhausts its stack it receives a `SIGSEGV` signal.

In my case, my program parses its input with a hand-written recursively descent parser which can exhaust its stack if the input file has a particularly deeply nested grammatical structure (think of the grammar of a programming language and an input file with very deep nested calls like `f(f(f(f(f(f(....))))))`).

My program has an option to run it with an increased stack size for cases like this, but I would like to handle `SIGSEGV` to suggest the user to use that option when the cause of the `SIGSEGV` is stack exhaustion.

Is there any way to tell that the program has received a `SIGSEGV` because of this reason instead of any other bug?

Comment: If you really anticipate input expressions so deeply nested that stack overflow is likely, then you should probably use a different parsing algorithm, with an explicit parser stack rather than recursion. If this issue occurs without extraordinary nesting (i e. with real user input as opposed to programmatically-generated expressions), you might also want to verify that your stack frames are not too large.

Comment: These cases are rare and do not deserve complicating the parsing algorithm, but are possible since the inputs to my program *are* usually machine-generated. I’m ok with my program crashing in such cases, I just want to suggest the user how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to tell that the program has received a SIGSEGV because of this reason instead of any other bug?

Yes.

1. Record the current stack size limit in `main()`, using [getrlimit](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html)(`RLIMIT_STACK`, ...). Store it in some global.
2. Record an address of a local variable in `main()`, store it in another global.
3. When entering parser, take an address of some local there.
4. *Estimate* current stack usage as `(char*)ptr_to_local_in_main - (char*)ptr_to_local_in_parser`.

IFF the current stack usage is within (say) 4-8KiB of the limit, you are in the danger zone. At that point you could:

1. Abandon the parse, tell end-user to increase stack, or
2. Set a global `in_danger_zone` flag, to be checked by `SIGSEGV` handler.

Alternatively, you could just record `ptr_to_local_in_parser`, and in your signal handler see whether the delta between `ptr_to_local_in_{main,parser}` is large enough that stack overflow is likely.

It's possible in the signal handler to examine `ucontext_t` passed into it, disassemble the instruction, figure out whether that instruction manipulates the stack (e.g. `PUSH`, `CALL`, `MOV 0x...(%RSP)`, etc.) and make a more precise determination, but the complexity is *probably* not worth the additional accuracy you would get this way.

Comment: That’s a clever solution!